# Is there any single word that means "let people know of my presence"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Sometimes we need to write a long expression in a single word. I need to know the single word or verb that means, "letting people know of one's own presence".

Here goes the context: There was this pair of macaws very close to me and I didn't notice them. They cried so loud all of a sudden that I felt they were trying to make me aware of their presence. And while writing about it I couldn't figure out the exact word to narrate the macaws' action.

Comment: It helps if you give the context in which you would use that word.

Comment: Kindly insert this detail in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, you can use `to manifest oneself`.

> **manifest** - to show something clearly, through signs or actions

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manifest).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single word that means all that. You could use 'announcing myself' if you have arrived somewhere, or 'revealing myself' if you have come out of hiding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the expression ***to make one's presence felt/heard/known***:

> If someone or something makes their presence felt, they do something that makes you notice them or pay attention. ([free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+your+presence+felt))

I am not sure you can find a single word for this meaning.

Comment: Hi , Thank you so much. That will be very helpful.